# Can I Define a Custom extension point in Apacahe Nutch 1.8

Tags: java, apache, web-crawler, nutch, information-retrieval

I need to use a postgre sql database instead of txt file for seed urls before running injector job. Can i achieve this problem by using plugin system ? If I can, which extension point I should use or Should I define a custpm extension point ?

Comment: Please explain the issue more thoroughly and eliminate the typos.

Comment: This issue is well explained IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no extension point for doing this. Either export the URLs from Postgres into a text file or rewrite the injector so that it can read from it - which would be more complex.

If you are on Nutch 2.x, GORA has a SQL connector which might work with Postgres.